# How to automatically remove a contact from specific group, if end date is added to specific relationship

Tags: groups, relationships, hooks

If end date is added to relationship,the contact should be automatically removed from the specific group.
How this can be accomplished?Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You can use civicrm "Smart Group" option for that purpose. Like this:

Go to Contact Advanced search, set the relationship type you want as a filter and other filters if you want, like contact type, etc.

After search is complete, select the `All X records` radio option in "Select Records" field. Then you in `Actions` dropdown menu `Create Smart Group`. Smartgroup automatically updates its contacts list based on the criteria you had set.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Make sure that 'Relationship Status' is 'Active' in Advanced Search

Answer (score 2):

If smart groups don't do what you need then you could also remove them from a static group with [CiviRules](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules)